# Web.config Asp.net 5 Changes after Publish with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, configuration, visual-studio-2015, web-config, asp.net-core

I'm Using Visual Studio 2015's "Publish" functionality to deploy a Web App. I'd like to change it so that the after Publishing, the web.config file contains the following snippet:

```
  <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="Hosting:Environment" value="Staging" />
  </environmentVariables>
```

I tried adding the above snippet directly to the web.config file in the VS project like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform
      processPath="%DNX_PATH%"
      arguments="%DNX_ARGS%"
      stdoutLogEnabled="true"
      stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout"
      startupTimeLimit="3600"
      forwardWindowsAuthToken="true">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="Hosting:Environment" value="Staging" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, the output of the Publish command still produces the web.config file without my additions:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform 
      processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" 
      arguments="" 
      stdoutLogEnabled="true" 
      stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout" 
      startupTimeLimit="3600" 
      forwardWindowsAuthToken="true">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Am I missing something? Is there anything else that I have to do in order for the Published version of the web.config file to reflect these changes?

Comment: Are you using any config transformation at the time of publishing? Do you have any Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config in your project?

Comment: My last information on that is that you can't publish to IIS yet via VS2015, only Azure. For IIS you need to use `dnu build` to build it, manually copy it over to the desired folder and set up a web application in iis manually that points to the apps wwwroot folder

Comment: @TejSoft No just one web.config file

Comment: @Tseng You are able to publish via VS2015. See [link](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#publish-from-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Gulp to add any snippet you want to web.config (or any other file for that matter) at publishing:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-gulp.html?highlight=gulp